# Не могу получить объект из промиса

Tags: reactjs, json, promise

Моя проблема заключается в получении ответа с сервера, сервер возвращает promis через функцию

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

const password = 'Valantis';
const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).split('-').join('');
const data = `${password}_${timestamp}`;

const authorizationString = CryptoJS.MD5(data).toString();;

export async function getStore() {
        await fetch("http://api.valantis.store:40000/", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Auth': authorizationString
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(
                {
                    action: 'get_ids'
                }
            ),
        }).then( res => {
           res.json().then(results => 
            {let result = results
                if (result !== undefined) {
                    console.log(result)
                    return result
                }
             })
        }
     );
}
```

Эту функцию я вызываю в state productStore в другом файле

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { getStore } from './http/productStore';

const productsStore = {
    productsList: getStore().then(res => console.log(res))
}

function reducer(state = productsStore, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "SET_LIST": return {...state, productsList: action.products };
        
        default: return state;
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

, и в файле App.js вывожу в консоль этот state

```
import { useSelector } from'react-redux';
import ProductCard from './components/ProductCard';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import AsideMenu from './components/AsideMenu';

function App() {
  
  const products = useSelector(state => state.productsList)
  console.log(products)

  return (
    <Container style={{padding: "50px 30px 0 50px", display: "flex", justifyContent: 'space-between'}} className='d-flex '>
      <Container style={{display: "flex", flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
       
      </Container>
      <Container style={{border: "1px solid black", padding: '30px', backgroundColor: '#87cefa', minHeight: '300px'}}>
      <AsideMenu></AsideMenu>
      </Container>    
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

, вот в итоге что получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы понимаете, что делаете вот этой строкой `getStore().then(res => console.log(res))`? Да и начальное состояние должно быть константой

Comment: Не особо, я просто пробую всё подряд. А можно с конст поподробнее пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых, код `getStore().then(res => console.log(res))` всегда вернет **undefined**, т.к. из последнего `.then()` ничего не возвращается.

Пример

```js
// Это наш промис
async function test() {
  return {
    a: 'answer'
  }
}
// Тут будем ждать выполнения
async function run() {
  // Дожидаемся промисов и записываем рещзультат
  const x = await test().then(x => console.log(1, x));
  const y = await test().then(x => {
    console.log(2, x);
    return x
  });
  console.log('=========')
  // Выводим значения переменных
  console.log('x', x)
  console.log('y', y)
}
// Запускаем
run();
```

Теперь модифицируем код, что бы он корректно работал и реагировал на изменение состояния.
Для начала зададим начальное состояние для хранилища

```
const productsStore = {
  productsList: []
}

function reducer(state = { ...productsStore }, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case "SET_LIST": return {...state, productsList: action.products };

    default: return state;
  }
}
```

В компонент App добавляете вызов вашей функции при установке компонента

```
function App() {
  const products = useSelector(state => state.productsList)
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    getStore().then(res => dispatch({type: 'SET_LIST', products: res}))
  }, []);
  // Тут ваш код рендера
}
```

Как компонент будет установлен в DOM, произойдет вызов вашей функции запроса данных. Когда данные придут, они сохранятся в stor redux и компонент обновится.

Ну и так как вы ожидаете в ответе массив, то что бы не было неожиданного поведения, в функции getStore я бы в then изменил код вот так, что бы всегда гарантированно приходил массив

```
.then(result => {
  return result ? result : []; // Если пусто, пернуть пустой массив
})
.catch(err => []) // Если ошибка, вернуть пустой массив
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо большое за помощь!

Вот конечный вариант вызова

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';


const password = 'Valantis';
const timestamp = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).split('-').join('');
const data = `${password}_${timestamp}`;

const authorizationString = CryptoJS.MD5(data).toString();;




export async function getStore() {
    const res = await fetch("http://api.valantis.store:40000/", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Auth': authorizationString
        },

        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                action: 'get_ids'
            }
        ),

    }).then(response => response ? response : []).catch((err) => [])
    return res.json()
}
```